# Can not change metadata of my custom Integromat app which is in testing by Integromat

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

My app in testing and i must change color of logo (theme). It is possible? I do not see the button to edit metadata.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done from the [Integromat Apps SDK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Integromat.apps-sdk) plugin for Visual Studio Code.
Right-click on the app name and choose "Edit metadata":

[image: Integromat VS Code plugin: Edit metadata]

You'll then be able to change the app label, description, theme and some additional settings:

[image: Integromat VS Code plugin: Customize theme]